Is it possible to store and retrieve PFX (PKCS12) keystore in Azure Key Vault
I want to import private key and the certificate chain (PFX file) to Azure Key Vault. In Java Spring application, I would like to retrieve the PFX from key vault for Java keystore creation. Is this possible with Azure Key Vault and Java SDK?

Could you please edit your question and include more details like what code you tried and any error you faced?


I want to import private key and the certificate chain (PFX file) to Azure Key Vault.

I have followed below steps to import the PFX certificate with private key in Azure key vault.

Navigate to Azure key vault=>Certificates, select Generate/Import Certificate.
Select Import as Method of Certificate Creation, upload the PFX certificate and enter the password. Click Create.


Use below code to retrieve the certificate using Java, refer MSDOC:
@RequestMapping("/")  
public void hello()   
{  
    String keyVaultName = "<Keyvault_Name>";
    String certificateName = "<Certificate_Name>";

    CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
            .vaultUrl("https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net")
            .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
            .buildClient();

            KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.getCertificate(certificateName);
            System.out.printf("Received certificate with name \"%s\", version %s and secret id %s%n",
            certificate.getProperties().getName(), certificate.getProperties().getVersion(), certificate.getSecretId());
}  

Response:
2024-10-03T15:52:06.580+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-10-03T15:52:06.660+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-10-03T15:52:06.680+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.443 seconds (process running for 4.339)
2024-10-03T15:52:35.080+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
//Other logs
2024-10-03T15:52:47.634+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential  : Azure Identity => Attempted credential AzureCliCredential returns a token
2024-10-03T15:52:47.635+05:30  INFO 4992 --- [demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.c.implementation.AccessTokenCache    : {"az.sdk.message":"Acquired a new access token."}
//Retrieved Certificate details
Received certificate with name "pfxcer", version a97518bff5104aXXX8524c595dcb and secret id https://KeyvaultName.vault.azure.net/secrets/pfxcer/a97518bff5104aXX9fa8524c595dcb

